# Cordova plugin: danwilson/google-analytics-plugin not working on android device

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to use the google analytics on Cordova  app,
I've followed the instruction on the the repository , and all works well on the chrome android emulator .
I see live activity on google analytics site.

but when i log into the app from the device , it seems the analytics is not recognizing the the app.

in my config.xml I have :

```
 < access origin="*" >
```

In the android manifest I have the permissions :

```
android.permission.INTERNET 

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

When running in debug mode , i see the app is indeed going into the

```
cordova.exec(success, error, 'UniversalAnalytics', 'trackView', [screen]);
```

function , but it doesn't display any data on the google analytics view

any ideas?

Comment: Do you happen to  print something in your success or error callbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems Google analytics is updated after 24 hours or so when using the mobile Api.

Although I don't see any activity in the 'live-view' section
I can see a log of my activities on the site from previous days (eCommerce analytics)