# Cordova and Google Analytics Plugin

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I have been trying for hours now, to make this plugin work on a Cordova 5.1 app.

https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

Supposedly, following the easy instructions I should be able to track pageviews and events on my app, but I can't see anything going on in my Google Analytics account.

I created an APP account as suggested everywhere. I go to real time and check with no success. Here is my little code:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    navigator.splashscreen.hide();   

    if (typeof window.analytics !== 'undefined'){
        console.log("We got Analytics");
        window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-67560028-3', function(){ 
            console.log("Started OK");
            window.analytics.trackView('Home');
        });

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Google Analytics plugin could not be loaded.")
    }

}
```

I can see "Habemus analyticsss" from Dalvik console, as I build the app and install it on my device. When I run "cordova plugin list", I can see the plugin properly installed:

```
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.0 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

By the way, here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.labrtve.trazosurbanos" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the docs for the plugin?

> Important Note If the latest versions (0.8.0+) of this plugin are not working for you with Android on Cordova 5.0+, please try to use an earlier version while the fix is researched via:
>
> > cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics@0.7.1

Comment: Nice try! I hadn't seen that before. It doesn't make any difference though...  window.analytics is ready but I can't see anything going on on Google Analytics.

Comment: Try adding a callback:
window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXXX-3', function(){//log tracker started;}); and see if this is actually started before your next line of code gets executed. It could be that you are calling trackView but your tracker hasn't started yet. And if it's the case, move your trackView code to the success function body.
Just out of curiosity, have you tried the 0.7.1 version? It might be that you would still get an analyitics object but it wouldn't be sending the data to google.

Comment: Yes, I removed the last version and installed 0.7.1. I am getting de successful log in the callback function, all good. Is it maybe that it will take plenty of time to show up on Analytics?? like stated here... [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122565/cordova-plugin-danwilson-google-analytics-plugin-not-working-on-android-device

Comment: If you're using the "Realtime" tab on analytics then you should see it right away. Please tell me that this is what you're looking at =)

Comment: Yes it issss heheheheh. Of course! by the way, I created an APP (not a website) tracking account in Google Analytics.. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Just to confirm, did you try moving your tracking code inside the success function?

Comment: Yes I did. Nothing happens.. I have internet connection on my phone, the APP wouldn't work without it..

Comment: There it is amrhady (edited on the original question), thanks a lot... it must be something else.. it is like there is no communication at all, I should be seeing results in Google Analytics Real Time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89678/discussion-between-rmartrenado-and-amrhady).